# Using a Python pandas dataframe column as input to a loop through another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I've got two dataframes. One looks like:

```
Year  Count
1      3
2      2
3      1
4      5
5      4
```

The other looks like

```
ID   Value
1     100
2      50
3       0
4      25
5      50
```

I'm looking to use the Count in first dataframe to loop through the second dataframe. I want to use the count value in each row to randomly select from the Value column in the second dataframe N times where N is the value in the Count column - and add these values up, giving a new column in the first dataframe thus:

```
Year  Count  RandSum
1      3      200
2      2       50
3      1      100
4      5      225
5      4      200
```

i.e. so the RandSum column added to the first dataframe is the sum of "Count" random selections from the Value column in the 2nd dataframe (i.e. in the first row, Count = 3, so drawing randomly from the Value column in the 2nd table drew 100, 50 and 50 = 200)

Any help appreciated for this relative python novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another idea using [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) in a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df1['RandSum'] = [np.random.choice(df2['Value'], n).sum() for n in df1['Count']]
```

[out]

```
   Year  Count  RandSum
0     1      3      175
1     2      2       50
2     3      1       50
3     4      5      275
4     5      4      200
```

Comment: Thank you - I gave this a crack as it was a one-line answer and it worked well - cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use `sample` for this, then take the sum rowwise

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Count': [3, 2, 1, 5, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Value': [100, 50, 0, 25, 50]})
df['RandSum'] = df.apply(lambda x: df2['Value'].sample(x['Count']), axis=1).sum(1)

print(df)
```

Output (Will vary by run)

```
   Year  Count  RandSum
0     1      3    150.0
1     2      2    150.0
2     3      1     50.0
3     4      5    225.0
4     5      4    225.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you should import pandas and create data frames. then, you select the column you want to iterate through with a `for` loop function. Afterward, you randomly choose a number of values in the target column and sum it. finally, put it into the output column named `RandSum`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Count': [3, 2, 1, 5, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Value': [100, 50, 0, 25, 50]})

df1["RandSum"] = np.nan
for i, count in enumerate(df1["Count"]):
    sample = df2["Value"].sample(n = count)
    df1.iloc[i, df1.columns.get_loc("RandSum")] = sample.sum()

df1.head()
```

The output will be different every time we run it.

| Year | Count | RandSum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 125.0 |
| 2 | 2 | 150.0 |
| 3 | 1 | 25.0 |
| 4 | 5 | 225.0 |
| 5 | 4 | 175.0 |